# explode() into $key=>$value pair

Tags: php

I have this:

```
$strVar = "key value";
```

And I want to get it in this:

```
array('key'=>'value')
```

I tried it with explode(), but that gives me this:

```
array('0' => 'key',
      '1' => 'value')
```

The original $strVar is already the result of an exploded string, and I'm looping over all the values of the resulting array.

Comment: Why don't you just create your array out of the `explode()` results?

Comment: and then do `$myArray[$ar[0]] = $ar[1];` where `$ar` is the exploded string.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Don't believe this is possible in a single operation, but this should do the trick:

```
list($k, $v) = explode(' ', $strVal);
$result[ $k ] = $v;
```

Comment: Thanks, this way has more efficient mem use. TIP: When `foreach` is using this recursive making a large array, you can `unset()` the original/source array after `$result` is populated. This will trim memory. Ie, when parsing Google shopping categories from their [crappy] txt file a temp array is created using `file()` then `explode()` on each row string to isolate an ID as the key. The source array has 5425 rows containing strings. That array is ~1mb, and its temporary, nuke it :)

Comment: How values are stored in `$result`?

Comment: This and the other answers seem to work for one value and one key only.

Comment: @AnujTBE $result is created as a consequence of the assignment.

Comment: @Elyor it's one of the more obscure features of php but it really deserves some syntax sugar. Python does ok here with iterable unpacking but javascripts destructuring assignments are my favorite (works for lists AND objects) - i really wish the php core could get inspired by the syntax candy that modern javascript offers.

Answer (score 10):

```
$my_string = "key0:value0,key1:value1,key2:value2";

$convert_to_array = explode(',', $my_string);

for($i=0; $i < count($convert_to_array ); $i++){
    $key_value = explode(':', $convert_to_array [$i]);
    $end_array[$key_value [0]] = $key_value [1];
}
```

Outputs array

```
$end_array(
            [key0] => value0,
            [key1] => value1,
            [key2] => value2
            )
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Will you please explain why you think this is the correct answer?

Comment: This answer is correct and better to be used with `foreach()`

Answer (score 4):

```
$strVar = "key value";
list($key, $val) = explode(' ', $strVar);

$arr= array($key => $val);
```

**Edit:**
My mistake, used split instead of explode but:

> split() function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this
>   feature is highly discouraged

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
$str = explode(" ","key value");
$arr[$str[0]] = $str[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can loop every second string:

```
$how_many = count($array);
for($i = 0; $i <= $how_many; $i = $i + 2){
  $key = $array[$i];
  $value = $array[$i+1];
  // store it here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$pairs = explode(...);
$array = array();
foreach ($pair in $pairs)
{
    $temp = explode(" ", $pair);
    $array[$temp[0]] = $temp[1];
}
```

But it seems obvious providing you seem to know arrays and `explode`. So there might be some constrains that you have not given us. You might update your question to explain.

Comment: No, no constraints, I was just looking for a 'single line of code' solution :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
$keys = array();
$values = array();

$str = "key value"; 
$arr = explode(" ",$str);

foreach($arr as $flipper){
   if($flipper == "key"){
      $keys[] = $flipper;
   }elseif($flipper == "value"){
      $values[] = $flipper;
   }
}

$keys = array_flip($keys);
// You can check arrays with
//print_r($keys);
//print_r($values);

foreach($keys as $key => $keyIndex){
  foreach($values as $valueIndex => $value){
       if($valueIndex == $keyIndex){
          $myArray[$key] = $value;
       }
  }
}
```

I know, it seems complex but it works ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than 2 words in your string, use the following code.

```
    $values = explode(' ', $strVar);

    $count = count($values);
    $array = [];

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count / 2; $i++) {
        $in = $i * 2;
        $array[$values[$in]] = $values[$in + 1];
    }

    var_dump($array);
```

The `$array` holds oddly positioned word as `key` and evenly positioned word `$value` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

```
list($array["min"], $array["max"]) = explode(" ", "key value");
```

Comment: Please add some description to explain answer for benefit of other.

Answer (score 0):

Another single line:

```
parse_str(str_replace(' ', '=', $strVar), $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have long list of key-value pairs delimited by the same character that also delimits the key and value, this function does the trick.

```
function extractKeyValuePairs(string $string, string $delimiter = ' ') : array
{
    $params = explode($delimiter, $string);

    $pairs = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($params); $i++) {
        $pairs[$params[$i]] = $params[++$i];
    }

    return $pairs;
}
```

Example:

```
$pairs = extractKeyValuePairs('one foo two bar three baz');

[
    'one'   => 'foo',
    'two'   => 'bar',
    'three' => 'baz',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am building an application where some informations are stored in a key/value string.

> tic/4/tac/5/toe/6

Looking for some nice solutions to extract data from those strings I happened here and after a while I got this solution:

```
$tokens = explode('/', $token);

if (count($tokens) >= 2) {
    list($name, $val) = $tokens;
    $props[$name] = $val;
}

if (count($tokens) >= 4) {
    list(, , $name, $val) = $tokens;
    $props[$name] = $val;
}

if (count($tokens) >= 6) {
    list(, , , , $name, $val) = $tokens;
    $props[$name] = $val;
}

// ... and so on
```

*freely inspired by smassey's solution*

This snippet will produce the following kinds of arrays:

```
$props = [
    'tic' => 4,
];
```

or

```
$props = [
    'tic' => 4,
    'tac' => 5,
];
```

or

```
$props = [
    'tic' => 4,
    'tac' => 5,
    'toe' => 6,
];
```

*my two cents*

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is really an answer but it took me some time to figure out so I'm going to share this anyway.

I wanted to change

```
Array
(
    [0] => email= joeri@bespired.nl
    [1] => name = Joeri
    [2] => token= AB2240824==
)
```

into

```
Array
(
    [email] => joeri@bespired.nl
    [name]  => Joeri
    [token] => AB2240824==

)
```

And got that solved with:

```
$values = array_combine(
    array_map(fn($v) => trim(explode("=", $v, 2)[0]), $values),
    array_map(fn($v) => trim(explode("=", $v, 2)[1]), $values)
);
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

If you have more values in a string, you can use `array_walk()` to create an new array instead of looping with `foreach()` or `for()`.
I'm using an anonymous function which only works with PHP 5.3+.

```
// your string
$strVar = "key1 value1&key2 value2&key3 value3";

// new variable for output
$result = array();

// walk trough array, add results to $result
array_walk(explode('&', $strVar), function (&$value,$key) use (&$result) {
    list($k, $v) = explode(' ', $value);
    $result[$k] = $v;
});

// see output
print_r($result);
```

This gives:

```
Array
(
    [key1] => value1
    [key2] => value2
    [key3] => value3
)
```

Comment: Doesnt work. I get an Only variables should be passed by reference error

Answer (score -2):

Single line for ya:

```
$arr = array(strtok($strVar, " ") => strtok(" "));
```

Comment: If the down-voter could please elaborate on his reason for down-voting maybe we could learn something...

Comment: Not my downvote, but this is a code-only answer and these types of answers do very little to educate future readers.  If you want to earn rep points, please improve your answer to include an explanation as to why this is an appropriate method and how it works. (I know how it works BTW)

Answer (score -2):

I found another easy way to do that:

```
$a = array_flip(explode(' ', $strVal));
```

Comment: That will give you `array(key => 0, value => 1)`.  OP wants `array(key => value)`.