# How to parse the string to array

Tags: php

I have following value in a table column is there any option to get the `sandbox` value and `merchant_email` like array ? I know using explode and loop is works but any other smart options 
 ?
something like `$result->sandbox`

```
 paypal_merchant_email="sample@ymail.com"|paypal_verified_only="0"|payment_currency=""|sandbox="1"|sandbox_merchant_email="sample@ymail.com"|payment_logos=""|debug="0"|status_pending="W"|status_success="O"|status_canceled="D"|countries=""|min_amount="0"|max_amount="0"|secure_post=""|ipn_test=""|no_shipping="0"|address_override="0"|cost_per_transaction="0"|cost_percent_total="0"|tax_id=0|
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966693/explode-into-key-value-pair you mean?

Comment: I think the OP knows how to do it with explode etc, but is asking if there's a better way given that string format. I think exploding twice is perfectly good enough...

Comment: [Why dont you take the response as JSON and simple use `json_decode($result->sandbox, TRUE);`?](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/gs_PayPalAPIs/) Also it would help to see what you're currently using.

Comment: @Prix its not comes from paypal the Virtuemart is saving payment gateway details in this format in DB

Comment: @JobinJose I have also added a method using `preg_match_all` to the benchmark which is in question of writing probably the simplest one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little benchmark magic:

```
<?php
// explode
$start = microtime(TRUE);
$data = array();
foreach (explode('|', $result->sandbox) as $item)
{
    if (empty($item)) continue;
    list($key, $value) = explode("=", $item);
    $data[$key] = str_replace('"', '', $value);
}
print_r($data);
$stop = microtime(TRUE);
$timeResult = $stop - $start;
echo $timeResult, "\n";

//preg_split
$start = microtime(TRUE);
$data = array();
foreach (preg_split('/\|/', $result->sandbox) as $item)
{
    if (empty($item)) continue;
    list($key, $value) = preg_split('/=/', $item);
    $data[$key] = str_replace('"', '', $value);
}
print_r($data);
$stop = microtime(TRUE);
$timeResult = $stop - $start;
echo $timeResult, "\n";

//preg_match_all
$start = microtime(TRUE);
$data = array();
preg_match_all('/([^=]+)="([^"]+)?"\|/', $result->sandbox, $result);
$data = array_combine($result[1], $result[2]);
print_r($data);
$stop = microtime(TRUE);
$timeResult = $stop - $start;
echo $timeResult, "\n";
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [paypal_merchant_email] => sample@ymail.com
    [paypal_verified_only] => 0
    [payment_currency] =>
    [sandbox] => 1
    [sandbox_merchant_email] => sample@ymail.com
    [payment_logos] =>
    [debug] => 0
    [status_pending] => W
    [status_success] => O
    [status_canceled] => D
    [countries] =>
    [min_amount] => 0
    [max_amount] => 0
    [secure_post] =>
    [ipn_test] =>
    [no_shipping] => 0
    [address_override] => 0
    [cost_per_transaction] => 0
    [cost_percent_total] => 0
    [tax_id] => 0
)
0.00029397010803223

Array
(
    [paypal_merchant_email] => sample@ymail.com
    [paypal_verified_only] => 0
    [payment_currency] =>
    [sandbox] => 1
    [sandbox_merchant_email] => sample@ymail.com
    [payment_logos] =>
    [debug] => 0
    [status_pending] => W
    [status_success] => O
    [status_canceled] => D
    [countries] =>
    [min_amount] => 0
    [max_amount] => 0
    [secure_post] =>
    [ipn_test] =>
    [no_shipping] => 0
    [address_override] => 0
    [cost_per_transaction] => 0
    [cost_percent_total] => 0
    [tax_id] => 0
)
0.00031495094299316
```

Another:

```
Array
(
    [paypal_merchant_email] => sample@ymail.com
    [paypal_verified_only] => 0
    [payment_currency] =>
    [sandbox] => 1
    [sandbox_merchant_email] => sample@ymail.com
    [payment_logos] =>
    [debug] => 0
    [status_pending] => W
    [status_success] => O
    [status_canceled] => D
    [countries] =>
    [min_amount] => 0
    [max_amount] => 0
    [secure_post] =>
    [ipn_test] =>
    [no_shipping] => 0
    [address_override] => 0
    [cost_per_transaction] => 0
    [cost_percent_total] => 0
    [tax_id] => 0
)
0.00026917457580566

Array
(
    [paypal_merchant_email] => sample@ymail.com
    [paypal_verified_only] => 0
    [payment_currency] =>
    [sandbox] => 1
    [sandbox_merchant_email] => sample@ymail.com
    [payment_logos] =>
    [debug] => 0
    [status_pending] => W
    [status_success] => O
    [status_canceled] => D
    [countries] =>
    [min_amount] => 0
    [max_amount] => 0
    [secure_post] =>
    [ipn_test] =>
    [no_shipping] => 0
    [address_override] => 0
    [cost_per_transaction] => 0
    [cost_percent_total] => 0
    [tax_id] => 0
)
0.00028419494628906
```

Comment: What is the significance of your benchmark? It is pointless, and you are saving microseconds.

Comment: @RPM the significance is to show him that he could have done that from the start to see which method would perform the best to what he needs done but feel free to get mad at it.

Comment: @RPM Oh I am sorry that I actually have 3 different methods with a benchmark on it.

Comment: @JobinJose it seems the `preg_match_all` performs the best over 1k iterations.

Comment: @Prix The question wasn't about benchmarking. It was about parsing a string.

Comment: @RPM nope, from the comment sent on your answer `I am looking for better option bcoz that looping is take time if the string length high` but feel free to continue.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = 'paypal_merchant_email="sample@ymail.com"|paypal_verified_only="0"|payment_currency=""|sandbox="1"|sandbox_merchant_email="sample@ymail.com"|payment_logos=""|debug="0"|status_pending="W"|status_success="O"|status_canceled="D"|countries=""|min_amount="0"|max_amount="0"|secure_post=""|ipn_test=""|no_shipping="0"|address_override="0"|cost_per_transaction="0"|cost_percent_total="0"|tax_id=0|';

$result = array();
$string = preg_split('/\|/', $string);
foreach($string as $key => $value) 
{
    $value = str_replace('"', '', $value);
    $value = preg_split('/=/', $value);
    if(strlen($value[0])> 0) 
    {
       $result[$value[0]] = array_key_exists(1, $value) ? $value[1] : NULL;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [paypal_merchant_email] => sample@ymail.com
    [paypal_verified_only] => 0
    [payment_currency] => 
    [sandbox] => 1
    [sandbox_merchant_email] => sample@ymail.com
    [payment_logos] => 
    [debug] => 0
    [status_pending] => W
    [status_success] => O
    [status_canceled] => D
    [countries] => 
    [min_amount] => 0
    [max_amount] => 0
    [secure_post] => 
    [ipn_test] => 
    [no_shipping] => 0
    [address_override] => 0
    [cost_per_transaction] => 0
    [cost_percent_total] => 0
    [tax_id] => 0
    [] => 
)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. that same as explode and loop iam looking for better option bcoz that looping is take time if the string length high

Comment: See my edit. It is easier to just transform the whole thing into an associative array.

Comment: Thanks for your time +1 efforts

Comment: How is this different from normal explode() ? You are using simple regex that can be done easily with explode().

Comment: @AyeshK would recommend you do some benchmark on that as it may be heavier than using explode, however you would only know that by actually doing it and the different from both would be pretty insignificant.

Comment: @Prix the benchmark result is trivial and does not matter, as it won't make any significant difference.

Comment: @Prix yes but this answer does not include a benchmark result so I'm just wondering **why** RPM used preg_split. 
http://micro-optimization.com/explode-vs-preg_split

Comment: @RPM I meant no offense or asking others to downvote - I am just looking for something to learn.

Comment: @Ayesh K : because I like preg_split.

Comment: @RPM The better option is given by prix So i marked that as selected. thanks for your time

Comment: better by microseconds? have fun counting your microseconds.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function parse_str() but it is for & delimiter:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Or you can impress somebody with knowledge or PHP functions:

```
$str = 'a=13|b="string"|';

$rawarray = preg_split('/\|/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$keys = array_map(create_function('$a', '$r = preg_split("/=/", $a); return $r[0];'), $rawarray);
$values = array_map(create_function('$a', '$r = preg_split("/=/", $a, 2); return eval("return $r[1];");'), $rawarray);
$result = array_combine($keys, $values);

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need just one or two values, use regular expressions:

```
function get_value_from_string($key, $str) {
    return preg_match('/\|'.$key.'=([^\|]*)/', '|'.$str, $matches) ? eval("return $matches[1];") : null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, No friend I need almost all the values.

Answer (score 0):

Here's possibly a more elegant solution using `str_getcsv`, `array_walk`, `use`, `parse_str` and the venerable `each` (to extract the key / value pairs). With your data:

```
$string = 'paypal_merchant_email="sample@ymail.com"|paypal_verified_only="0"|payment_currency=""|sandbox="1"|sandbox_merchant_email="sample@ymail.com"|payment_logos=""|debug="0"|status_pending="W"|status_success="O"|status_canceled="D"|countries=""|min_amount="0"|max_amount="0"|secure_post=""|ipn_test=""|no_shipping="0"|address_override="0"|cost_per_transaction="0"|cost_percent_total="0"|tax_id=0|';
```

Idea is to first use str_getcsv to parse the `|`-separated line, then traverse it using fast PHP functions.

```
$t = str_getcsv( $string, "|" );
```

At this point, $t is a simple array containing broken up "key=value" pairs.

```
$new = array();
array_walk( $t, function( &$a ) use (&$new) {
    parse_str( $a, $b);            # parses each line, returns key-value
    $c = each( $b );               # need to obtain key-value from above
    $new[$c["key"]] = $c["value"]; # simple assignment
});
```

This requires PHP > 5.3.0 since it uses namespaces (use) in the anonymous function. However, if you made it this far, 
`print_r( $new );` gives you this:

```
Array (
    [paypal_merchant_email] => "sample@ymail.com"
    [paypal_verified_only] => "0"
    [payment_currency] => ""
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the very compact solution for you:

```
preg_match_all('/\|(.*?)="(.*?)"/', '|'.$string, $matches);
$result = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

Test it here: https://3v4l.org/rfBuc