# Explode into array (key->value)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Hey guys I'm looking for a solution to a little problem, the PHP seems to be functioning properly and I can't see any problems with the SQL Query, can anybody see anything blatantly wrong with my code? I'm really stuck here.

the contents of the "items" row are similar to the following:

```
30->0,31->0,32->0,36->0,33->10,29->0,35->0,6->0,5->0,8->0,9->0,7->0,14->0,15->0,10->0,17->0
```

I just need them to explode into an array and foreach value in that array, print on the page with their appropriate "key". I've looked here: [explode() into $key=>$value pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966693/explode-into-key-value-pair) and arrived at no conclusion - this is the full code, if anybody could help me out, tell me what I'm doing or maybe even point me in the right direction I'd be really happy.

```
$id = $_GET['order'];
if(!is_number($id)){
    exit();
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE id='$id'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $dataString = $row["items"];
    foreach (explode(",", $dataString) as $cLine) {
    list ($cKey, $cValue) = explode('->', $cLine, 2);
        $itemarray[$cKey] = $cValue;
    }

    foreach($itemarray as $key => $value) {
        echo "<br/>".$value." x ".$key;
    }
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: It's probably something really obvious but I have intense brain-failure at the minute and have a deadline.

Comment: What are the data types of your fields in your orders table?  (varchar, int, etc)

Comment: The string I'm trying to pull is a varchar, Steve.

Comment: Ok, what about the 'id' field?

Comment: Auto-incrementing INT field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my code **and** query are both perfect. The problem was here:

```
if(!is_number($id)){
    exit();
}
```

Either my ?order=55 wasn't recognized as a number or was misusing the is_number function.

Thanks for all your help guys.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet, so I'm posting an answer. The following code seems to work fine:

```
$dataString = "30->0,31->0,32->0,36->0,33->10,29->0,35->0,6->0,5->0,8->0,9->0,7->0,14->0,15->0,10->0,17->0";
foreach (explode(",", $dataString) as $cLine) {
  list ($cKey, $cValue) = explode('->', $cLine, 2);
  $itemarray[$cKey] = $cValue;

  foreach($itemarray as $key => $value) {
    echo "<br/>".$value." x ".$key;
  }
}
```

so my best bet would be that the data returned from the query isn't as expected.

Comment: Definitely a Query error then, you think? Thanks for running that, hadn't thought of doing so. I guess I'll have to tinker with the query until I find one that works.

Thanks a bunch, dude.

Answer (score 1):

For when you get the data worked out this should be easier:

```
parse_str(str_replace(array('->',','), array('=','&'), $row['items'), $itemarray);
print_r($itemarray);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, do you think I should re-format my database entires to use = and & as opposed to -> and ,?

Comment: If you have control over this I would restructure so each id and value is in their own row.

Comment: Trouble is, this is for an order system, the "key" in this function is the product and the value is the amount. All processed as one order. I guess I could assign some sort of unique identifier to each row. However this would conflict with the rest of the website. Thanks again.