# PHP list() error: "Undefined offset"

Tags: php, arrays, error-handling

I am dealing with a system which sends any unexpected errors back to me in a string with the error type, message, and details, for example:

```
      Error Type - Database
      Error Message - Error Executing Database Query.
      Error Detail - [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]String or binary data would be truncated.
```

Now to create a better UI I am expected to deal with these errors, so I thought about explode(), and found [this user's response in the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php#111307) which helped me delimit the results with two delimiters instead of just one:

Then I needed to get a little deeper into the code because I wanted $key => $val pairs, so I came across [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15966755/1527252).

Then I combined both and came across this solution:

```
private function string_to_array( $delimiters, $string )
{
    // start by replacing the $delimiters
    $ready = str_replace( $delimiters, $delimiters[0], $string );
    
    // create new list() item:
    // $key => $value
    list( $err_typ,     $err_typ_cont,
          $err_mess,    $err_mess_cont,
          $err_det,     $err_det_cont ) = explode( $delimiters[0], $ready ); # line 238
    
    $result[ trim( $err_typ ) ]     = trim ( $err_typ_cont );
    $result[ trim( $err_mess ) ]    = trim ( $err_mess_cont );
    $result[ trim( $err_det ) ]     = trim ( $err_det_cont );
    
    return $result;
}
```

To call the functions I am using `array('-', PHP_EOL)` as `$delimiters` and the `$string` is the error message as a `string`

---

It worked really well when I inserted a random error into a string and called the function. However, when I trigger a random error from the server, I start to run into issues, specifically, `Undefined offset` for my `list()` function

#### PHP error

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 5 in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\application\_backend\class\class.program.php</b> on line <b>238</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 4 in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\application\_backend\class\class.program.php</b> on line <b>238</b><br />
```

Also, note that the array comes all weird and wrong:

#### Response in an array format

```
Array
(
    [Error Type] => Database
          Error Message
    [Error Executing Database Query.
          Error Detail] => [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]String or binary data would be truncated.
    [] => 
)
```

This is the same error as I can see above.

How can I fix that? What am I missing here?

Comment: I can only imagine that the content of `$ready` from adjusting `$string` actually cannot explode into 6 items... like the delimiters are not matching up. Can you print_r() both of those before the explode to debug what they think they have?

Comment: @Randall actually I can: `Error Type - Database
          Error Message - Error Executing Database Query.
          Error Detail - [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]String or binary data would be truncated. `

Comment: @Randall that would be the same error as the one at the top

Comment: I'm thinking what `PHP_EOL` thinks is the return, is not what is in the `$string`, thus its just not str_replacing them with dashes?

Comment: @Randall I think you are right... :P but why would it not recognize `PHP_EOL`?

Comment: Try `var_dump(explode( $delimiters[0], $ready ));` before you do the list command to see if it's exploding the way you think it should be.

Comment: The API you're using is presumably not written in PHP, so it doesn't use the same newline convention as PHP does.

Comment: New lines could be `\n`, `\r`, or `\r\n`. `PHP_EOL` may just be set to `\n`

Comment: I tried `\n` and `\r` but neither work, or their combinations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system you're dealing with apparently uses a different newline character than the system running the PHP script. I suggest you handle all types of newlines:

```
$delimiters = array('-', "\r\n", "\n", "\r");
```

Comment: Add `"chr(13)"` to the end of that array. And also for precaution run this after `str_replace`: `$string = preg_replace("/(-){2,}/","-",$string);` to truncate multiple dashes into 1.