# store string with key and value in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string = `"Name":"Susan","Age":"23","Gender":"Male";`

How to store them in an array so that I can echo the value for example:

```
echo $array['Name']
```

or

```
echo $array['Age']
```

Thanks

Comment: go to php array w3 or google it

Comment: Take a look at `associative arrays` in PHP. It looks like that's what you need

Comment: Your answer is here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_array_assoc

Answer (score 2):

If your string is already:

```
"Name":"Susan","Age":"23","Gender":"Male"
```

That's almost JSON, so you can just enclose it in curly brackets and convert it to turn that into an array:

```
$decoded = (Array)json_decode('{'.$str.'}');
```

`json_decode()` normally outputs an object, but here we're casting it to an array. This is not required, but it changes how you have to access the resulting elements.

This would render the following associative array:

```
array(3) {
  ["Name"]=>
  string(5) "Susan"
  ["Age"]=>
  string(2) "23"
  ["Gender"]=>
  string(4) "Male"
}
```

Comment: `json_decode()` has a flag that will cast the data as an array.

Answer (score 1):

Associative Arrays in PHP are what you need to achieve your task. In PHP `array()` are actually ordered maps i.e. associates `values` with a `key` Here is an example. An associative array is an array where each key has its own specific value. Here's an example.

```
$values = array("Name"=>"Susan", "Age"=>"23", "Gender"=>"Male");
echo $values['Name'];
echo $values['Age'];
echo $values['Gender'];
```

Comment: fount the solution at this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966693/explode-into-key-value-pair ,

Answer (score 1):

You can store string as json

```
$json = '{"Name":"Susan","Age":"23","Gender":"Male"}';
$array = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($array);
```

The manual specifies the second argument of json_decode as:

> assoc
> When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18576902/5546916

Answer (score -1):

Try below snippet

```
$string = "Name":"Susan","Age":"23","Gender":"Male";

//explode string with `,` first
$s = explode(",",$string); // $s[0] = "Name":"Susan"....


$array = array();
foreach($s as $data){
    $t = array();
    $t = explode(":",$data); //explode with `:`
    $array[$t[0]] = $t[1];
}

echo $array["name"];
```