# Explode String many times into Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this:

```
$var = 'es@set:col-md-8 col-lg-4 col-xl-6|info:f1|but:md
fs@set:col-md-4 col-lg-8 col-xl-6|info:f4|but:md';
```

And I want to get it in this:

```
$arr = array(
  'es' => array(
    'set' => 'col-md-8 col-lg-4 col-xl-6',
    'info' => 'f1',
    'but' => 'md'),
  'fs' => array(
    'set' => 'col-md-4 col-lg-8 col-xl-6',
    'info' => 'f4',
    'but' => 'md'),
);
```

Many explodes: "\n" "@" "|" ":"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You haven't asked a question. What's the problem?

Comment: Sorry my english is not good, this "And I want to get it in this" was my question. My questions have been answered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [explode() into $key=>$value pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966693/explode-into-key-value-pair)

Answer (score 1):

This requires looping over the strings created by exploding on newline, getting a key/value pair by exploding on `@`, individual items for the key by exploding the value on `|`, and then the final key/value pairs by exploding each item on `:`

```
$var = 'es@set:col-md-8 col-lg-4 col-xl-6|info:f1|but:md
fs@set:col-md-4 col-lg-8 col-xl-6|info:f4|but:md';
$arr = array();
foreach (explode("\n", $var) as $item) {
    list($key, $value) = explode('@', $item);
    foreach (explode('|', $value) as $val) {
        list ($k, $v) = explode(':', $val);
        $arr[$key][$k] = $v;
    };
}
print_r($arr);
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [es] => Array (
        [set] => col-md-8 col-lg-4 col-xl-6
        [info] => f1
        [but] => md
    )
    [fs] => Array (
        [set] => col-md-4 col-lg-8 col-xl-6
        [info] => f4
        [but] => md
    ) 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/iirNu)