# Split string with only one delimiting character into key-value pairs

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, explode, delimited

I have a colon-delimited string like this:

```
"Part1:Part2:Part3:Part4"
```

With explode I can split the string into an array:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r(explode(":", "Part1:Part2:Part3:Part4"));
echo '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Part1
    [1] => Part2
    [2] => Part3
    [3] => Part4
)
```

But I need associative array elements like this:

```
Array
    (
        [Part1] => Part2
        [Part3] => Part4
    )
```

**UPDATE**

```
echo '<pre>';
list($key, $val) = explode(':', 'Part1:Part2:Part3:Part4');
$arr= array($key => $val);
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>';
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [Part1] => Part2
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [explode() into $key=>$value pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966693/explode-into-key-value-pair)

Comment: I updated my first post. The code doesn't work :(

Comment: Put that list thing in a loop.

Comment: I'm just wondering why your pairs aren't separated by a different delimiter. Do you have control over the generation of that string?

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49563864/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-multidimensional-recursive-array-in-php)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
$string = "Part1:Part2:Part3:Part4";
$arr = explode(":", $string);

$key = "";
$i = 0;
$newArray = [];
foreach($arr as $row){
    if($i == 0){
        $key = $row;
        $i++;
    } else {
        $newArray[$key] = $row;
        $i = 0;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArray);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution using only array_* functions.

- Collect all values that are going to be keys for the resultant array.
- Collect all values that are going to be actual values for the resultant array.
- Combine both using `array_combine()`.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$str = "Part1:Part2:Part3:Part4";

$res = array_combine(
        array_map(fn($v) => $v[0], array_chunk(explode(':',$str),2)),
        array_map(fn($v) => $v[1], array_chunk(explode(':',$str),2))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a for loop, you could also use the modulo operator `%` and create the key in the `if` part.

The if clause will be true for the first item having the key first and then the value in the else part, toggeling the keys and the values.

```
$str = "Part1:Part2:Part3:Part4";
$parts = explode(':', $str);
$result = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($parts); $i++) {
    $i % 2 === 0 ? $k = $parts[$i] : $result[$k] = $parts[$i];
}    
print_r($result);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [Part1] => Part2
    [Part3] => Part4
)
```

[See a php demo](https://3v4l.org/9KJB0)